# Plumeria Transplant Advice

Tags: transplanting

I have a cutting that's been growing in a pot for about a year. It needs to be re-potted in something larger, but I'm concerned about doing this during the growth period.

Additionally, should the media be similar to the perlite and potting soil I used for rooting or do I need to move on to something else?

For what it's worth, I'm in region 9b.

Thanks much,
MB

Comment: pictures get answers

Comment: How would a picture help? You know the plumeria is root-bound and that it is growing. I'm just asking whether it's OK to repot during the growing season.

Comment: people are visual

Answer (score 1):

Plumeria, as in Hawaiian plumeria? This is the Best time to repot, let the roots get established.When I lived in Hawaii, we had one in the front yard. I took a cutting, rooted it, then put it in the ground in the back yard. No special medium needed, just fertilize when it's needed. Look up the more exotic plants on-line for a lot of help. Good Luck.

Comment: Actually, I believe the cutting was from Florida, but it looks like other plumeria cuttings I've had from Hawaii.One important note, I'm in the Bay Area, not Hawaii, so I don't have as ideal an environment, hence my concern.

Comment: belanger. I'm in up-state NY.! When you say Bay Area, I'm thinking Calif.? I would think, warm climate,plenty of water and fertilizer? I need a little more info on your general location. Of course, I Don't grow them here. :)